# Delete specific widget in a list full of the same widget

Tags: flutter

How do i delete a specific widget when I press on a GestureDetector?? When I press a container, it adds a new ClassContainer (the yellow container) and stores it in the a list called List classes which is in the InputPage class. What I want to do now is when I press on the GestureDetector, I want that specific ClassContainer (the yellow container) to be removed. I have linked an image below for you to see. I would really appreciate your help!

**This is inside my InputPage file which is the first page (as seen on the image linked below), it adds all the different classes/files together.**

```
class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  List<Widget> classes = []; //where the widgets are stored inside

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            DisplayFeature(totalUnits: classes.length),
            AddNewSubject(
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  classes.add(ClassContainer(
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        classes.removeAt(**I don't know what to do here**);
                      });
                    }
                  ));
                });
              },
            ),
          ]..addAll(classes),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is inside my ClassContainer file, which contains the entire container (the yellow container). Only a part of the file is shown below**

```
class ClassContainer extends StatefulWidget {

  ClassContainer({this.onPressed});
  final Function onPressed;

  @override
  _ClassContainerState createState() => _ClassContainerState();
}

String selectedCredit = 'Regular';

class _ClassContainerState extends State<ClassContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                flex: 7,
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
                    hintText: 'Class',
                    hintStyle: kClassTitle,
                  ),
                  style: kClassTitle,
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: widget.onPressed,
                child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.restore_from_trash,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

[Open this to see a picture of what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp9PW.png)

Comment: have you tried classes.removeAt(classes.length - 1); ?

Comment: @dubace thanks for your help! but sadly that removed the last container (the yellow container) in the array full of containers. I need to find a way to get the specific container (the one i'm pressing on the GestureDetector) one I want to delete.